# Getting image and text from facebook post

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-4.x

Is there any possibility to extract/get the image and description from Facebook post in code?

Let say we have a public post 
https://www.facebook.com/rihanna/photos/a.207477806675.138795.10092511675/10154095214621676/?type=3&theater

Do we able to extract/get the image and description(Get the new dance remixes ...) of that particular post by using Facebook sdk in code?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. You can access the Graph API through a GET request and the photo ID (in your case it's `10154095214621676`). As long as the photo originates from a public page you can call for different parameters like `name` (that's the description), `picture` (small image), etc.

You can play around with the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/) to figure out what exactly you need. For a more detailed information on the possible parameters you might want to have a look into the Facebook Developers [Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/photo/). There you can also find some examples how to handle requests in different SDKs.

Answer (score 0):

Agreed with trotta.

Something like this https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895?method=GET&path=10154095214621676%3Ffields%3Dpicture%2Cname%2Calbum%2Cimages&version=v2.9

and you can get all info for the post.

Comment: Thanks a lot that was more helpful for me because you put PhotoId on right place and I easily understand how do you get the image